# Joomla component with AJAX/jQuery populating #containers

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, joomla

I've been reading up extensively on incorporating AJAX into my Joomla component, but I feel like I'm missing a step.  Here is the structure I have so far:

**AJAX CALL**

```
var url = "index.php?option=com_mls&task=ListData&format=raw";

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {         

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function() {
                $('#content').load('data.php');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**data.php**

```
$array = [! I need a way to get the results from controller.php !]

foreach($array as $key => $value){
    echo "<div>" . $value['2']; "</div>
}
```

**controller.php**

```
function ListData()
{
    $query = [! A bunch of "JRequest::getVar" that builds the query !];
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $array = $db->loadRowList();

    echo (json_encode($array));

}
```

The step I'm missing is getting the data FROM the controller task and into the `#content` node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#submit').click(function() { 
     var url = "index.php?option=com_mls&task=ListData&format=raw";
     $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#content').html(data);
        }
    });
  });
});
```